# What should be avoided to write memory-leak-safe code using STL?

Tags: c++, stl, memory-leaks

I've used STL for quite a while now, but mostly to implement algorithms for the sake of it, other than the occasional vector in other code.

Before I start using it more, I wanted to know what the common mistakes people make when using STL are -- in particular, are there any things I should watch for when using STL templates to keep my code safe from memory leaks?

Comment: This is a very vague question ...

Comment: If you allocate a container of pointers, removing from the container != deleting the pointer.

Comment: The most common problems are simply from using it too little, such as a program that uses collections in some places, but allocates raw memory in other, and the other parts don't manage their memory very well.

Comment: @Zac Howland: I'm looking for things a person might 'assume' about STL, introducing memory leaks they wouldn't have otherwise. Is there a way to better phrase the question?

Comment: Read "Effective C++", "Effective STL", and "More Effective C++" by Scott Meyers in addition to "Exceptional C++" and "More Exceptional C++" by Herb Sutter.  Those 5 books will answer 95% of all questions you might have in this regard (and will make it obvious why I said this is a very vague question).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a lot of bottlenecks in using STL effectively, if you want to know more I'd suggest the book ["Effective STL" by S.Meyers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629).

Answer (score 9):

When you store raw pointers to dynamically allocated objects in containers, containers won't manage their memory.

```
vector<FooBar*> vec;
vec.push_back(new FooBar); //your responsibility to free them
```

To make it more memory-leak proof use containers of smart pointers, or special-purpose pointer containers, as in Boost: [pointer containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html)

Particularly considering that if an exception gets thrown, execution might not reach the manual clean-up code (unless painful efforts are made).

Comment: That is of course correct, but not really STL-related: you always leak memory if you don't delete heap-allocated objects. I don't think that you can actually introduce memory leaks solely by using the STL if your code didn't have any memory leaks before. I think more important problems are things like dangling references or iterators.

Comment: @Philipp: Dangling iterators are important to know, however the question is about memory leaks. - People sometimes get the idea that STL containers will manage their pointers. I they think so, they can introduce new memory leaks, they wouldn't have caused if they had written all the code themselves.

Answer (score 6):

> in particular, are there any things I should watch for when using STL templates to keep my code safe from memory leaks?

STL or not, the answer is the same:

- Learn about exception safety
- Learn RAII: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization
- Learn about smart pointers: http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm
- Get a few "C++ moral guide" books, like Exceptional C++, and read them